# Background Worker and Parallel.For Null Exception

Tags: c#, backgroundworker, nullreferenceexception, parallel.foreach

I am trying to optimize a pixel value reader (from images) and tried to used Parallel.For with a Background Worker to show the progress on a bar. I an using a Dictionary to store the read values to be used for other processing. When I use only the Parallel.For, it works perfect and time is under minute. When I use Background Worker and Parallel.For then I receive null exception message at the point when I am trying to add the values to dictionary.

I am using C# .Net 4.

```
    public Dictionary<string, DNValuesSrcTrgt> ReadPixelValuesFromImages(
                                                string _trgtRasterName, 
                                                string _trgtRasterDirectory,
                                                string _srcRasterName, 
                                                string _srcRasterDirectory
                                                )
    {

        Dictionary<string, DNValuesSrcTrgt> dictSrcTrgtImgValue = null;
        IRaster2 trgtRasterData2 = null;
        IRaster2 srcRasterData2 = null;


        try
        {
            //Open both the target and source images are IRaster2 QI
            trgtRasterData2 = OpenIRaster2(_trgtRasterName, _trgtRasterDirectory);
            if (trgtRasterData2 == null)
            {
                return null;                    
            }
            srcRasterData2 = OpenIRaster2(_srcRasterName, _srcRasterDirectory);
            if (srcRasterData2 == null)
            {
                return null;                    
            }
            dictSrcTrgtImgValue = new Dictionary<string, DNValuesSrcTrgt>();

            //Create a Raster Layer class to get the Number of columns and rows
            //This is read from the target Raster Image
            IRasterLayer trgtRasterLyr = new RasterLayerClass();
            trgtRasterLyr.CreateFromDataset(trgtRasterData2.RasterDataset);


            //Loop through all the rows and column for Target Image and get the
            //Cell value and the X and Y value
            //Then use the X and Y value to get the Cell value from Source Image
            double xCord = 0.0;
            double yCord = 0.0;

            object valTrgt = null;
            object valSrc = null;


            int cnt = 0;


            string errorMessage = string.Empty;     
            int i = 0;



            Parallel.For(0, trgtRasterLyr.ColumnCount, (j, loopstate) =>
            {

                //if (UserAborted) return;
                for (int k = 0; k < trgtRasterLyr.RowCount; k++)
                {
                    DNValuesSrcTrgt srcTrgtImgValue = new DNValuesSrcTrgt();
                    cnt++;

                    srcTrgtImgValue.columnID = j;
                    srcTrgtImgValue.rowID = k;

                    valTrgt = trgtRasterData2.GetPixelValue(i, j, k);
                    //Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(val1), 5);
                    trgtRasterData2.PixelToMap(j, k, out xCord, out yCord);

                    int colSrc = srcRasterData2.ToPixelColumn(xCord);
                    int rowSrc = srcRasterData2.ToPixelRow(yCord);

                    valSrc = srcRasterData2.GetPixelValue(i, colSrc, rowSrc);

                    srcTrgtImgValue.xCord = xCord;
                    srcTrgtImgValue.yCord = yCord;
                    srcTrgtImgValue.DNImageTrgt = Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(valTrgt), 5);
                    srcTrgtImgValue.DNImageSrc = Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(valSrc), 5);

                   //**This is where Error is Occuring**

                   dictSrcTrgtImgValue.Add(j.ToString() + "," + k.ToString(), srcTrgtImgValue);


                    valTrgt = null;
                    valSrc = null;
                }

            });      
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            dictSrcTrgtImgValue = null;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            GC.Collect();
        }
        return dictSrcTrgtImgValue;
    }
```

Comment: Please show us the code with That backgroundworker.

Comment: Please include exception details so we're not in the dark and guessing...

Comment: From the code shown, you never instantiate `dictSrcTrgtImgValue`, so it would be null if you're not instantiating it. Are you instantiating it somewhere else?

Comment: Also, you probably want to use `ConcurrentDictionary` instead of `Dictionary` since you're using multiple threads (of course, I don't know what you're using because that code isn't shown, but I thought it was relevant to add).

Comment: Hi Pete... I has instantiated the dictSrcTrgtImgValue outside the loop. As I am adding values to this dictionary to be used in another method, I will try using ConcurrentDictionary and will let you know if it works:)

Comment: Hi Pete .. added full method. Will let you know after testing.

Comment: Hi Pete ... The code works after using ConcurrentDictionary. However the when I analyzed the values recorded in the dictionary, they are all wrong. Values were right before using Backgroundworker.

Comment: One more problem ... when code is run on Backgorund, it takes at least twice the time as compared to when run without.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your dictionary declaration with this one.

```
public ConcurrentDictionary<string, DNValuesSrcTrgt> ReadPixelValuesFromImages(
                                            string _trgtRasterName, 
                                            string _trgtRasterDirectory,
                                            string _srcRasterName, 
                                            string _srcRasterDirectory
                                            )

ConcurrentDictionary<string, DNValuesSrcTrgt> concurrentdictSrcTrgtImgValue = null;
```

This makes more sense when you're using **multiple managed threads** drawn from the Task Parallel Library (on Parallel.For) **on** the **same DataStructure**.